C# System.ExceptionArgument Bad Namespace?
For C#, I am trying to compile Dictionary.cs from GitHub. I am trying to tweak the Dictionary library.
I am getting various errors, like:

Error (active) CS0234
The type or namespace name 'IDictionaryDebugView<,>' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    DictionaryTest1 C:\Users\Erik\source\repos\DictionaryTest1\DictionaryTest1\Dictionary.cs
Error (active) CS0103
The name 'ThrowHelper' does not exist in the current context  DictionaryTest1 C:\Users\Erik\source\repos\DictionaryTest1\DictionaryTest1\Dictionary.cs
Error (active) CS0103
The name 'ExceptionArgument' does not exist in the current context    DictionaryTest1 C:\Users\Erik\source\repos\DictionaryTest1\DictionaryTest1\Dictionary.cs>
Error (active) CS0103
The name 'NonRandomizedStringEqualityComparer' does not exist in the current context  DictionaryTest1 C:\Users\Erik\source\repos\DictionaryTest1\DictionaryTest1\Dictionary.cs

My question is, how do I resolve these four errors, without having to download their source code (again) and recompiling those libraries too?
Can't I just include the namespace or DLL files instead?
I got Dictionary.cs from: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs
I just copied Dictionary.cs into my C# project and compiled it along with my program.cs file and main method.
I am doing this because I have the Book Programming C# 10 by O'Reilly, and I am messing around with a Dictionary class code example.
This is an example function that has some of these errors:
public Dictionary(int capacity, IEqualityComparer<TKey>? comparer)
{
    if (capacity < 0)
    { 
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.capacity);
    }

    if (capacity > 0)
    {
        Initialize(capacity);
    }

    // For reference types, we always want to store a comparer instance, either
    // the one provided, or if one wasn't provided, the default (accessing
    // EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default with shared generics on every dictionary
    // access can add measurable overhead).  For value types, if no comparer is
    // provided, or if the default is provided, we'd prefer to use
    // EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals on every use, enabling the JIT to
    // devirtualize and possibly inline the operation.
    if (!typeof(TKey).IsValueType)
    {
        _comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;

        // Special-case EqualityComparer<string>.Default, StringComparer.Ordinal, and StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.
        // We use a non-randomized comparer for improved perf, falling back to a randomized comparer if the
        // hash buckets become unbalanced.
        if (typeof(TKey) == typeof(string) &&
            NonRandomizedStringEqualityComparer.GetStringComparer(_comparer!) is IEqualityComparer<string> stringComparer)
        {
            _comparer = (IEqualityComparer<TKey>)stringComparer;
        }
    }
    else if (comparer is not null && // first check for null to avoid forcing default comparer instantiation unnecessarily
         comparer != EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default)
    {
        _comparer = comparer;
    }
}

For the above method: ThrowHelper, ExceptionArgument and NonRandomizedStringEqualityComparer are showing red underlined IntelliSense errors.
I don't want to have to also compile those three classes, and then have to recompile the missing references in the three classes that I also compiled. This is because I will have to recursively download and compile these source files. I don't want to end up with like 100 source files that I have to download, and I want to be able to resolve these errors without having to do that.

Sounds like you need more code

Is there a way to bulk download all of the needed source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib,namespaces I want to bulk download from mscorlib.

I forgot to ask if I can somehow download all of this in one package from github.com? https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/tree/master/mscorlib

If you forget to ask something, you can edit your question to ask it and add more details.

You may not necessarily need the source code, but you do need to add all the required assembly references to your project.

These classes are not the public .net libraries, you need get the source codes for them or copy the codes into your current project.

That ThrowHelper you can replace with throw new ArgumentException(..)

There's a nice green "Code" button shown on https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/tree/master which offers various means to access/copy the code. But just be aware, it's not that common to want/need to actually compile this code.

why not use https://github.com/dotnet/runtime ?

@Erik343 Why are you trying to "tweak" the Dictionary class in the first place anyway? That sounds like an XY problem.

@BrandoZhang - how is the question related to asp.net-core ?!?

Modifying the core library is something that basically shouldn't be needed by any C# developer. (If you find a bug, report it and get it patched.) You shouldn't expect to be able to compile just one class without having the rest of the internal code that it relies on available. It's unclear what you're hoping to achieve by "tweaking" Dictionary, but it's highly likely that there's a better way of achieving it.

I have an example in my book, Programming C# 10, and I need to modify Dictionary.cs to figure out an example in the book. I am trying to checkout MSCORLIB right now from GitHub.

Instead of using github.com/microsoft/referencesource/tree/master, I used https://github.com/dotnet/runtime. This repo has Dictionary.cs, and I was able to compile that code.
